# TSQL, SELECT statement in CASE in COUNT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, subquery, aggregate-functions

I can't find any explanation to why my thinking in wrong.
I want to do something like :

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (SELECT [Number] FROM [SOMETABLE] WHERE [id] = [GivenId]) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM [SomeOtherTable]
```

I keep getting

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

It would be nice to understand why cant I do what i want to do.

AND ALSO it would be nice to know what can i do different in-order to get the same result.

Comment: I don't see anything bad with the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use COUNT(an aggregate function) with a unrelated table i.e. there must be some relation between the table [SOMETABLE] and [SomeOtherTable].

One possible way to make this work would be: [SQL code here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82672/1)

If you cant access the link, here is the schema code:

```
create table yourtable (id int, graduates int, group_code varchar(100));

insert into yourtable values 
 (1, 50, 'others'),(1, 20, 'something'), (2, 20, 'total'), (3, 35, 'total2'), 
 (4, 40, 'total3');

create table othertable (ids int, graduate int, class varchar(100))
insert into othertable values (3,2, 'others')
```

Your modified statement:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (o.ids) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
FROM yourtable as y inner join othertable as o on y.group_code = o.class
where o.graduate = 2
```

**Thanks Giles, I changed the COUNT aggregate function to SUM

Comment: Should this not be `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (o.ids) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )` ?  Count returns the number of records whether they're 1 or 0 so this result above will be the same as the number records returned by the main query.